# Why are selenium ChromeDriver create null session in unix base OSs?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, centos7

I developed a app to read some web pages using `Selenium`.

`ChromeDriver` on windows worked correctly but in unix base Oss (Mac & Centos7) does not worked!

I think a problem is "Forwarding newSession on session null to remote" in the unix base OSs.

Some warnings and info when I ran app in unix base OSs are as bellow:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 102.0.5005.61 (0e59bcc00cc4985ce39ad31c150065f159d95ad3-refs/branch-heads/5005@{#819}) on port 53751
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1658989503.540][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 103.

28-Jul-2022 10:55:03.613 INFO [Forwarding newSession on session null to remote] org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession Detected dialect: W3C
28-Jul-2022 10:55:03.673 WARNING [main] org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder.findNearestMatch Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 103, so returning the closest version found: a no-op implementation
28-Jul-2022 10:55:03.673 INFO [main] org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder.findNearestMatch Unable to find CDP implementation matching 103.
28-Jul-2022 10:55:03.674 WARNING [main] org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.lambda$new$3 Unable to find version of CDP to use for . You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.1.0` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
```

Are there any solutions to resolve `ChromeDriver` error?

If you have any suggestions that can be help me, please add comment or answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Starting ChromeDriver 102.0.5005.61 (0e59bcc00cc4985ce39ad31c150065f159d95ad3-refs/branch-heads/5005@{#819}) on port 53751
.
[1658989503.540][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 103.
.
28-Jul-2022 10:55:03.613 INFO [Forwarding newSession on session null to remote] org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession Detected dialect: W3C
28-Jul-2022 10:55:03.673 WARNING [main] org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder.findNearestMatch Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 103, so returning the closest version found: a no-op implementation
28-Jul-2022 10:55:03.673 INFO [main] org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder.findNearestMatch Unable to find CDP implementation matching 103.
28-Jul-2022 10:55:03.674 WARNING [main] org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.lambda$new$3 Unable to find version of CDP to use for . You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.1.0` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [***Version 4.3.0***](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v103.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=103.0.5060.53/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=103.0* (as per [chromedriver=103.0.5060.53 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/103.0.5060.53/notes.txt)).

Comment: After upgraded selenium-java, selenium-api, selenium-remote-driver & selenium-chrome-driver depedencies to 4.3.0 but exists "Forwarding newSession on session null to remote" too. i wrote that in windows worked correctly but in centos7 does not work.

Comment: After upgrade console info is: ChromeDriver was started successfully.
28-Jul-2022 18:32:48.865 INFO [Forwarding newSession on session null to remote] org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession Detected upstream dialect: W3C
28-Jul-2022 18:32:48.955 INFO [main] org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder.findNearestMatch Found exact CDP implementation for version 103